# I deleted a C file from my system using rm-rf

Tags: linux, rm, file-recovery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to recover a removed file under linux](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)
>   [Undo an “rm -rf ~” command?](https://superuser.com/questions/279733/undo-an-rm-rf-command)

I deleted a newly created C file from my system. My assumption was that I did a `svn commit`. But I forgot to add the new C file to svn repository. And surprisingly it did not give me an error.
My problem is I tried the recovery suggested using `init 0` and `grep` but that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way at all that I can recover the C file? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a generic file recovery question, or something more specific?

Comment: Depends on your file-system. I remember reading that an alternative file-system (ReiserFS?) is able to undelete files. You don't give us your file-system, so there's no way to be sure if recovery via using the file-system is possible.

Comment: When this is all over, please consider using a revision control system. And/Or a configuration management system.