# Accidentally partially deleted home directory . . . Killed with ctl-c, which file is corrupted?

Tags: history, rm, timestamp, command-history

I was running some software in my home directory (last time I do that!). Stupid config file asks what directory I wanted to put my output files.  I accidently used `~/` as my output directory.  It created a `~` directory in my home folder.  I tried to delete it with `rm -r ~`, which of course started deleting my home directory.

Immediately (an eternity in clock cycles), I killed it with `ctl-c`.  There are no backups (this is beyond my control), so that is not a solution.

1. Is there a way to figure out which file or files have been corrupted?
2. Does `rm` actually change the timestamp of files?
3. Is there a history for `rm` so that I can figure out which files I've deleted?

Comment: Nope, take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/279733/undo-an-rm-rf-command

Comment: Well, did `rm` delete `$HOME/~` before you killed it?

Comment: No, it did not.